# CSS Creating a non-rectangular header for a hybrid app page

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am in the process of designing the layout for the pages of a hybrid Cordova/Android app where I need to use a non-standard, not rectangular, header.  The shape I wuold like to get is like the one shown below

[image]

I am trying to accomplish this with pure CSS3 and have got a fairly decent result thus far as shown below.

```css
 body,html{padding:0;margin:0}
 .ust
 {
  height:4vh;
  width:100vw;
  position:relative;
  background-color:orange;
  display:block;
 }
 .oval
 {
  position:absolute;
  height:12vh;
  width:160vw;
  top:1vh;
  left:-30vw;
  border-radius:100%;
  background-color:orange;
  display:block;
 }
 .timer
 {
  position:absolute;
  height:10vh;
  width:10vh;
  border-radius:100%;
  background-color:orange;
  left:calc(50vw - 5vh);
  top:9vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class='ust'>
 <div class='oval'>&nbsp;</div>
 <div class='timer'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

My effort does not look quiet as nice as the version I am trying to copy principally because of the way the "timer" element meets the "oval" - in a sharp corner.  The roundedness of the junction in the sample image is missing.

I have tried to work in the roundedness using the `timer::before/after` pseudo-elements and playing with their individual borders but try as I might I cannot get that concave junction effect.

I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to suggest a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to do that is with a clip path. This is a great website that generates the CSS code you need of the path to create that unique shape:

https://bennettfeely.com/clippy